# Django migrations with foreign key

Tags: python, django, migration

I' trying to migrate this model:

```
class Questionpart_image(models.Model):
    questionpart = models.ForeignKey(Questionpart, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField()
```

to this:

```
class Questionpart_image(Questionpart): # notice this base class
    image = models.ImageField()
```

to make advantage of inheritance. Django produces the following migration:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('ochsite', '0016_auto_20150809_1903'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='questionpart_image',
        name='id',
    ),
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='questionpart_image',
        name='questionpart',
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='questionpart_image',
        name='questionpart_ptr',
        field=models.OneToOneField(default='', primary_key=True, to='ochsite.Questionpart', serialize=False, parent_link=True, auto_created=True),
        preserve_default=False,
    ),
]
```

but this does not set the right foreign key to `questionpart_ptr` from `questionpart` field. How can I achieve that?
I've been searching for a long time, but nothing...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply don't rely on automatic migrations, make your own or modify that one.

Simplest solution will be by moving `AddField` in migration to the top of the list and inject between it and `RemoveField`s `RunPython` block that will rewrite id's from old field to new (and in other direction in reverse, if needed).

Comment: Thank you, I ended up with creating completely new models, migrating data and deleting old models. It's a bit more complicated but it's safe.